# How to make background/border start after content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a date as the following image, however I have trouble placing that dashed line in the same line as the date.

[image]

The main problem is I can't change the markup. I have the following structure:

```
<li class="activity-date-grouping">
    <span>4 Apr 2013</span>
</li>
```

and I can't add another element. I've tried with borders and background, but I can't move the line up. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTWhG/) with the border. Is it possible to achieve that without an extra element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't change the existing structure, you could instead use a pseudo element:

```
.activity-date-grouping { 
   /* ... */
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.activity-date-grouping span:after{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    content: ".";
    border-bottom:1px dashed #911c51;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hTWhG/4/

Comment: I was trying to figure out what to use for `content:` before I posted... The `.` looks good.

Comment: Impressive, I need to learn more about pseudo elements. That did it! Thank you!

Comment: You might consider using `.activity-date-grouping span:after` to avoid conflicts with any other `<span>` elements.

Comment: @gameower pseudoelements are VERY useful... Learn to love them :)

Comment: @PaulWoidke Fair point.  I was messing around in the fiddle and didn't go back and clean that up.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike James Montagne's solution, this one allows the element to wrap still:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/sukywzdz

```
.activity-date-grouping span {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  color: #911c51;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.activity-date-grouping span:after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px dashed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    /* optional */
    position: relative;
    left: .5em;
}
```

The demo has the styles attached to the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do what you want using absolute position but it's not very clean:

```
.activity-date-grouping span {
    position: absolute;   
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

[See the update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTWhG/3/)

Comment: This also does the trick, but i'll go with @James Montagne answer! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I didn't know we could do that with pseudo elements but yes it's the best solution

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTWhG/6/), seems to be displayed as you would like to. The key is to add some CSS to the `span` element itself. Note that it should work in older browsers too, because I didn't use the :after pseudo class or the "content" property...

```
.activity-date-grouping { 
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 5px 22px 5px;
    color: #911c51;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 70px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #911c51;
}

.activity-date-grouping span { position: absolute; margin-left: -110px }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following CSS for span

```
span
{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTWhG/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with no absolute positions using appropriate background images:

```
li.activity-date-grouping {
    background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png);
    background-position: 0px 0.8em;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100px 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.activity-date-grouping span {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ezxn/

Answer (score 0):

Wow, people here are too fast, but I'll post my code just for the heck of it. Here are two possible solutions, the first the better one (as other posts have shown):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.activity-date-grouping span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #911c51;
    position: relative;
}

.activity-date-grouping span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 105%;
    bottom: 0.2em;
    width: 999em;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #911c51;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li class="activity-date-grouping">
   <span>4 Apr 2013</span>
</li>
<ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And the other:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul {list-style: none;}
.activity-date-grouping {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #911c51;
}

.activity-date-grouping span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #911c51;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li class="activity-date-grouping">
    <span>4 Apr 2013</span>
</li>
<ul>

</body>
</html>
```